# UITableViewCell dynamic height unexpected behavior when adding image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm using Autolayout to dynamically adjust the size of my `UITableViewCell`, the height of the cell is determined by the height of a `UIStackView` that's shows several `UILabel`s, that's the height I want the cell to be, but I also added an Accessory `UIImageView`, that should adjust the stack's height, but not the other way around.

Since the image is downloaded from a `URL`, when first loaded, it work's just fine, as expected, but when the cell is reused, it resizes the cell so the height corresponds to the image's height, so it looks hideous.

**Summary of the issue**

A UITableViewCell is been automatically resized to fit an image, instead of the intended stack.

**Here's the code for the cell**

Note that the automatic height works beautifuly without the image.

As you might see, the stack is responsible for the bottom anchor of the whole `contentView`, and image only references it's anchors for it's size, not the other way around.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configureConstraints()
    }

func configureConstraints() {
        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        contentView.addSubview(imageContainer)
        
        stack.addArrangedSubview(header)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(middle)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(footer)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            imageContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            imageContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            imageContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            
            stack.firstBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: contentView.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: stack.lastBaselineAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        ])
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584123/6257435

Comment: @DonMag you're right, the issue had to do with intrinsic sizes, what I ended up doing is I made a Thumbnail of the original image to "best-fit" the canvas size, then the current constraints just work, it's worth mentioning that using thumbnails is a good practice anyway when you can't be certain the images are lightweight.